# How to prevent IllegalStateException in reactor when you need to block

Tags: java, spring-webflux

We have a synchronous process that needs to call two REST endpoints, whereas the result of the first is needed for the second. Using Springs WebClient the `.block()` causes the following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread parallel-2

How can this be prevented?

Here is a simplified code snippet:

```
var job = webClient.createJob().block();
if (job == null || StringUtils.isBlank(job.getId())) {
    throw new Exception("WebClient did not return with a job id");
}
batchRecords(job.getId(), records);// does some additional calls to the webClient
```

This works in the unit test, but when called through a `@RestController` the above exception is thrown.

EDIT:
The batchRecords method currently also has blocking Monos in it, so we can have a delay in between:

```
public void batchRecords(final String jobId, final List<InventoryRecord> records)
    var recordCount = 0;
    var inventoryPositions = new ArrayList<InventoryPosition>();
    var recordIterator = records.iterator();
    while (recordIterator != null && recordIterator.hasNext()) {
        var inventoryRecord = recordIterator.next();
        inventoryPositions.add(mapInventoryPosition(inventoryRecord));
        recordCount++;
        if (inventoryPositions.size() == batchSize) {
            var response = createBatch(jobId, inventoryPositions);
            Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
            response.block();
            inventoryPositions = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to block. You can use reactive operators (flatMap) instead.

Comment: @lkatiforis flatMap only transforms the object in the Mono to a new object and is still async.

Answer (score 1):

You should do it reactively without blocking:

```java
webClient.createJob()
    .filter(job -> !StringUtils.isBlank(job.getId()))
    .flatMap(job -> batchRecords(job.getId(), records))
    .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new Exception("WebClient did not return with a job id")));
```

As soon as the `createJob` operation is finished, the result is filtered and provided to the `flatMap` operator. In case of an empty response (`Mono.empty()`)  an exception is thrown.

Comment: Thanks, it seems I should have been more precise. I need to loop over the records and as the name implies batch them up in configured numbers. Plus they then need to block as well as we need a delay in between the batches. will update the question accordingly.

Comment: @Thomas you should never block. Use `delayElement(Duration.ofSeconds(sleepTime))` operator to introduce a delay between the bathes.